# Changing a continuous color scale with POSIXt objects

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose we have a series of positions in a 2D space that change over time:

```
start.time <- strptime("2016-11-22_15-44-24",
                       format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S",
                       tz = "UTC")

end.time <- strptime("2016-11-22_17-25-12",
                     format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S",
                     tz = "UTC")
date <- seq.POSIXt(from = start.time, to = end.time, length.out = 100)
a <- seq(0, 10, length.out = 100)
x <- a * cos(a)
y <- a * sin(a)
my.df <- data.frame(date, x, y)

ggplot(my.df, aes(x, y, color = date)) + geom_point()
```

This gives the following graph:

[image]

Now I would like to change the color palette to something more "dynamic", say the *Spectral* palette of the color brewer.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537782/how-to-set-fixed-continuous-colour-values-in-ggplot2), I used that commands:

```
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")))
sc <- scale_colour_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100))

ggplot(my.df, aes(x, y, color = date)) + geom_point() + sc
```

But I have an error:

> Error in Ops.POSIXt((x - from[1]), diff(from)) :
>   '/' not defined for "POSIXt" objects

(Rough translation from the actual error I get, which is half English/half French).

I guess at some point, scale_color_gradientn tries to divide my time scale in equal parts, and fails to do so because it doesn't know how to divide dates.

What can I do then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do a little numeric work around like this with `scale_color_distiller`:

```
library(lubridate)
ggplot(my.df, aes(x, y, color = as.numeric(date))) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_distiller(palette = "Spectral",
                          breaks = as.numeric(my.df$date[c(1,50,100)]),
                          labels = paste0(hour(my.df$date[c(1,50,100)]), ":", minute(my.df$date[c(1,50,100)])),
                          name = "date")
```

[image]

`scale_color_brewer` will only work for discrete date