# Create standard color scale for several graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a custom color scale for several graphs. I would like it to be a standard color scheme so that the two graphs can be compared. The data for the first graph has a much smaller range (its maximum is just a bit above 3) while the other one goes to 9. Therefore, I need colors to match numbers 4-9 but do not want them to appear in the first graph. However, they always do and I do not understand why.

Here is the data for the first graph:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100),
  y = runif(100),
  z1 = rnorm(100),
  z2 = abs(rnorm(100))
)
```

And here is the graph, with the custom color scale. However, as you can see all the colors appear in the graph even though only the first 5 colors should show up.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = z2))+scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c('springgreen1', 'springgreen4', 'yellowgreen','yellow2','lightsalmon','orange','orange3','orange4','navajowhite3','white'),breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Related: [How to set fixed continuous colour values in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537782/how-to-set-fixed-continuous-colour-values-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `limits` term of `scale_colour_gradientn` can help here:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = z2))+
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c('springgreen1', 'springgreen4', 'yellowgreen','yellow2',
                                     'lightsalmon','orange','orange3','orange4','navajowhite3','white'),
                         breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 
                         limits = c(0,9)) +
theme(legend.key.height = unit(1.5, "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works great. However, in my real data I have many breaks and so the labels on the color bar now overlap (i.e. the bar is too short). Do you know how to make the color bar longer so that there is more space between each number associated with each color?

Comment: You can change the legend size using `theme(legend....`, as shown in updated answer.