# Draw a circle with color according to it's density (frequency)

Tags: r, plot, density-plot

I have throw a ball, and I have record the distance between ball and me every time. I can draw a density plot according to ball distance from me. However, I would like to draw a circle, with its radius as max throwing distance.

Besides, I would like to use color gradient to represent the region with different frequency of ball counts (as density plot).

How can I achieve this with R?

Comment: ggplot density plot with coord_polar?

Comment: For example,
I use mtcars as example.
`plot(density(mtcars$mpg))`
I can obtain a density plot with the data mpg.
I would like to draw a concentric color gradient circle.
Just as this circle
[link]https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/faded-concentric-circles-radial-gradient-450w-689518015.jpg
With the darkest part as most frequent ball position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `geom_segment` with `coord_polar` (for that you will have to pre-calculate density yourself).

```
library(ggplot2)
# Lets calculate frequency of how far is the ball
d <- density(chickwts$weight)
# Here x is weight (or distance for OP) and y is frequency
pd <- data.frame(distance = d$x, frequency = d$y)

ggplot(pd, aes(x = 1, xend = 2, y = distance, yend = distance, color = frequency)) +
  geom_segment(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_color_viridis_c() +
  labs(
    title = "How far is the ball",
    x = "Distance",
    y = "Distance",
    color = "Frequency"
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

If categorical grouping is needed one can use this:

```
# Check if frequency is within wanted range
pd$color <- pd$frequency > 0.002 & pd$frequency < 0.003    
ggplot(
  pd,
  aes(x = 1, xend = 2, y = distance, yend = distance, color = color)
) +
  geom_segment(stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_color_viridis_d() +
  labs(
    title = "How far is the ball",
    x = "Distance",
    y = "Distance",
    color = "Frequency"
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, would it be possible to choose desired color region for the frequency?

Comment: @Bing-HongHuang Please explain, I don't really get what you want

Comment: @Bing-HongHuang please check my updated answer

Comment: For example, if the lowest frequency is purple while the highest frequency is green, may I change it as "lowest frequency is green and highest frequency is purple"?

Comment: @Bing-HongHuang it's not really related to original question - what you need is `scale_color_*`. Check tutorials like: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_colour_continuous.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537782/how-to-set-fixed-continuous-colour-values-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 0):

Using *mtcars* as example data, plot density, then convert to polar:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) +
  geom_density() +
  coord_polar()
```

[image]